# Asymptote: 3D fill color is undesired

Tags: 3d, asymptote, fill

I want to use Asmptote to draw a small triangle in red inside a unit cube. Here is my code:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
size(4cm,0);
import three;
draw(unitbox);
triple p0 = (0.8,1,0);
triple p1 = (1,0.8,0);
triple p2 = (1,1,0.2);
draw(surface(p0 -- p1 -- p2 -- cycle),red);
draw(p0 -- p1 -- p2 -- cycle);
```

However, color of the triangle is not desired. How could I resolve it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Change "red" to "emissive(red)".  Your triangle looks black because it has no direct light shining on it... it is in shadow.  The "emissive" wrapper makes it "emit" light.